# jQuery multiple methods waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous, hide

Is there a way to wait for hide function in a loop? I mean if I have this structure in html:

```
<div class='example'>
    <span> One </span>
    <span> Two </span>
    <span> Three </span>
<div>
```

And in js I want to do something like this:

```
$('.example span').each(function(i, span) {
    $(span).hide('slow');
});
```

I believe js is asynchronous so it will not wait for hide to end, but maybe there is a way which I don't know to wait until hide animation finishes and continue on next element?

Comment: Check Link.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to run them at the right times, like this:

```
$('.example span').each(function(i, span) {
  $(span).delay(600 * i).hide('slow');
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/D3AKg/)

All we're doing here is delaying the next animation 600ms ([the "slow" duration](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L455)) times it's index, so the first starts instantly (0-based, 0*600=0), the second at 600ms (the first should finish then), the third at 1200ms, etc.

Comment: who is **i** here? why it autoincrements?

Comment: @Syom - `i` comes from the callback function provided to the `.each()`, it's the first argument, and it's the index of the item in the array `.each()` is iterating through...so for our purposes, yes, auto-incrementing :)

Answer (score 2):

I use the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library for managing this sort of stuff:

```
async.forEachSeries($('.example span'), function(span, callback) {
  $(span).hide('slow', callback);
});​
```

This will run each hide function in series, without relying on a delay function which has to match the speed of the hide animation.

[You can try it out here.](http://jsfiddle.net/D3AKg/1/)

Admittedly, it might not be worth including another library just for this one issue, but if you run into problems ordering asynchronous calls such as animations and ajax functions a lot then I recommend you take a look :)

You can find the [async.js library on github](http://github.com/caolan/async)

Answer (score 1):

You can [call a function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) when hiding animation is complete - hide the next one from that callback.

```
function hideTags()
{
  var tags = $('.post-taglist a');
  var len = tags.length;
  var hide = function(i){
    if(i >= len)
      return;
    tags.eq(i).hide(1000, function(){hide(i + 1);});
  };
  hide(0);
}
```

Run this from your Firebug console to see your tags disappearing one after another.

Comment: You're calling 2 different methods ;)  Also you should use `$('.post-taglist a').eq(i)` rather than creating, throwing away and re-creating a new object, for that matter I'd cache the result set once and get your `.length` property off it as well.

Comment: @Nick updated - cached the result set; but now there are three functions in all. /disclaimer: am not a seasoned jQuery programmer.

Comment: Oh by two functions I meant the `hideTag` and `hideSpan` inconsistency :) What you have is much improved...one note though, you don't need to check the length and return. `.eq()` will just find no elements and the chain won't execute :)

Comment: @Nick Oh.. that was a typo due to copy pasting between SO page and the firebug console. I thought `eq` will throw index-out-of-bounds or something like that -  Firebug tells me it just returns an empty jQuery object; is it correct to assume that hide() method won't be invoked on that object (what would it hide anyway - but I'm more concerned about the code running forever in the background)?

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar thought and posted a question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

[My code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/jquery-delay-slidedown-using-queue) went something like:

```
var jParent = jQuery(".parent");
jParent.children().reverse().each(function()
{
    var jThis= jQuery(this);
    // queue puts the function in the normal "fx" queue. This means that the first one will always be fired automatically.
    jParent.queue( function()
    {
        jThis.slideDown(function()
        {// Dequeue Sets the next one going after the slideDown finishes
            jParent.dequeue(); 
        });

    });
});
```

Someone posted as answer that looked like: (simplified)

```
var DURATION = 500;

.each(function(index){
    var jDiv = $(this);

    jDiv.delay(DURATION * index);
    // used a variable delay to deal with the timing
    jDiv.slideDown(DURATION);
});
```

Personally I think the second one is easy to understsand but its more a matter of preference than anything IMHO.

some light reading: [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)